# Call Powershell script from Azure Web Job

Tags: java, powershell, azure, azure-webjobs

I need to install and call a Powershell script from an Azure Web job. The Powershell script will then call a java based command line tool.

And also, in an Azure environment, how would I know what the path to the files (Powershell and Java) would even be?

I am thinking of something like this:

```
private static void CallPowershell([QueueTrigger("queueName")CloudQueueMessage, TextWriter log)
{
  Process.Start("/pathToFile.ps");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does it *need* to be a script on that server? You could have a webhook to an Azure Automation script

Comment: Good point Michael B.  What I actually need to do is call a command line based tool written in java. I am guessing that I have to install that tool somewhere, and I was guessing that I would wrap the call in a Powershell script. Does Azure Automation work in this scenario? I am relatively new to Azure.

Comment: In that case that is probably not the best way to go! I'm not much of a Java person! but you could potentially run a java web job have a read of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariok/archive/2011/01/05/deploying-java-applications-in-azure.aspx) see if it puts you on the right track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a PowerShell script in WebJobs is native, but here is a post on how to get it done.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicktrog/archive/2014/01/22/running-powershell-web-jobs-on-azure-websites.aspx

The challenge will be how to make that PowerShell run the Java code.

Comment: That is definitely the challenge.